# send mail from linux command line using bcc and from headers

Tags: linux, email, command-line

I would like to send (batch) emails from a linux (ubuntu, postfix) command line.

I would like to include a bcc header (that actually sends the mail to this address), and
I would like to give a from: address.

I do not need attachments, text only. However, unicode support would be nice (not essential).
I would like a solution that is simple and robust (less important: will works on other machines/MTAs as well)

So far I tried:

- sendmail. This works great, but the BCC headier is ignored (which might be a postfix setting? I would not want to modify my postfix settings...
- mutt. can be used via command line, but then you have to create an own muttrc for the from: header, and there you might have to change some other settings too; again this does not seem very simple or robust.
- the old "mail" command  does not seem to work as expected in newer versions, at least the one I get on ubunto does not recognice the -b (bcc) option.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Thanks for the answers; I ended up using mutt (with a new muttrc just for this purpose) which turned out to work well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a **local** mail server running (exim, sendmail, ...) you can pipe a full, properly formatted message into it and it will be delivered. You must have a complete set of header (From:, To:, Cc:, Date: ...), there must be a blank line after the headers and before the message text, e.g.

```
exim -t -i < fullyFormattedMessage.txt
```

Most mailservers will pretend to be sendmail and will accept the -t flag.

Comment: You probably want `-i` was well, which prevents a line containing only `.` from ending the message. I've edited this in for you.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4458460/841108) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546856/841108) seems quite related to yours (at least if you want to code a command-line program which may send emails)

You could use [libsmtp](http://libsmtp.berlios.de/), [libesmtp](http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/), [libvmime](http://www.vmime.org/) etc.

And many scripting languages (Python, Ruby, Perl, ...) have several mail sending facilities.

On Debian, the [mime-construct](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/mime-construct-1.9/mime-construct) command is able to send a message in BCC, and you can find many other mailing utilities.